# My EventListener to a button continues to fire despite ownership being changed, why? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, which at the end of its task assigns a button to a new id.

```
function altChecker() {
    var doc = document,
        out = [],
        appButton = doc.getElementById('appButton'),
        //re = /click-me/gi,
        output = doc.createElement('p');

    output.setAttribute('id', 'output');

    EventUtility.addHandler(appButton, 'click', function(e) {

//I have not included all the function details to concentrate on the question

        appButton.id = 'appButtonNextChecker';
        var appButtonNextChecker = doc.getElementById('appButtonNextChecker');

        nextChecker(appButtonNextChecker);

    });

}

function nextChecker(newBtnName) {
    EventUtility.addHandler(newBtnName, 'click', function(e) {
      $('#output').innerHTML = "";
      console.log('next Checker, button!')
    });
}
```

So basically there is one button in the DOM assigned to `appButton` ID initially, and then I change it doing:

```
appButton.id = 'appButtonNextChecker';
```

when the `altChecker` function fires...

Then I assign the button to a new variable, and pass in the variable to the next function...

```
var appButtonNextChecker = doc.getElementById('appButtonNextChecker');

nextChecker(appButtonNextChecker);
```

While I can see the buttons' ID change in the DOM, and I see the `console.log` fire in the `nextChecker` function,

```
$('#output').innerHTML = ""; //doesn't fire
```

AND the `altChecker` function fires as well (again)?! Haven't I severed the connection to the `click` function when I reassigned the new ID?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't remember that you initially attached the event through it's id. The event is attached to the element itself, not the ID. It's not like CSS that way.

In fact your variables are still holding the same element as well, so there's no need to create a new variable after changing the ID, either. Since you're using jQuery you can just type [`$(appButton).unbind();`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the event handler. You may also want to look into [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property in a jQuery's object.

That property belongs to [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), and it will not work in the way you're using it.

You can use the `document.getElementById` method, and it will work fine:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';
```

Or you can use jQuery's [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$('#output').html('');
```

And you can even use the first element of the jQuery's array, and use `innerHTML` again:

```
$('#output')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

It's up to you, but the first option will be faster, for sure.